# Azure Front Door and DNS Configuration for SSL "bare" (without www) Custom Domain

Tags: azure, ssl, dns, azure-front-door

I've successfully configured SSL / HTTPS for my custom domain - with a "www" in the URL - using the Azure Front Door product. That configuration required a DNS CNAME entry that forwards "www.cutegoat.com" to "cutegoat.azurefd.net"

I still have an SLL problem when I go to the same URL without the "www" prefix: "https://cutegoat.com"

My A Type DNS record still points to an IP address that Azure gave me for my App Service. I thought about changing that, but the Azure Front Door designer is pretty clear that my "Custom host name" must have a corresponding CNAME record:

[image: Azure Front Door CNAME record required]

I'm using GoDaddy for my domains and I've added a CNAME record with a source of "cutegoat.com", but I still get the Azure Front Door "CNAME record required" error. That entry let's me add a mapping to "cutegoat.com.cutegoat.com"

I think the Azure Front Door service is looking for a CNAME record with a source value of "@". But I can't enter that CNAME record, my guess is, because I have an A Type record with a source of "@" already.

[image]

Does anyone know the proper DNS / Azure Front Door configuration to get SSL working for my "bare" custom domain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, since you must have an A Type record with a source of `@` already. You could not add such host `@` in the CNAME record as the CNAME limitation in [RFC1034](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034)

> If a CNAME RR is present at a node, no other data should be present; this ensures that
> the data for a canonical name and its aliases cannot be
> different.

As far as I know, currently Azure front door does not support to add Naked or root Domains to the custom host name. If you want to improve this service, you can request feedbacks or upvote this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/35530549-add-custom-apex-naked-domains-as-front-end-hosts)--- Add Custom Apex (Naked) Domains as front end hosts for Azure Front Door Service

Comment: Thank you Nancy.  
Based on a comment from the feedback link you provided, it sounds like I can create an A record with the IP that cutegoat.azurefd.net resolves to, but that IP may change periodically.  I think I will look at redirecting apex domain requests to the www subdomain for the time being.

Comment: Yes, currently you could not use apex domain for the Azure front door. You can redirect the apex domain requests to its subdomains.

Comment: @Dudeman3000 Speaking from experience, yes the Public IP address may change, but you are usually in control of this: If you scale-up from a non-premium to a premium service plan (or down from premium to non-premium), your IP address will change. If you switch from SNI to IP SSL your IP address will (probably) change. Finally, the one time Azure has had to change a public IP address on one of my web apps, they gave us two weeks notice and run both the old and new in parallel (i.e. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/ip-address-change-inbound)

Comment: Front Door is kind of useless without being able to add an apex domain without an azure provided SSL. Im planing to move to a third party service for geolocation rules.

Answer (score 5):

This appears to be working now, using an Alias type.

I use Azure DNS, so image is from there.

1. Added a new A record for the @ apex
2. Set it to an Alias
3. The Frontdoor service now shows up under the Azure Resource.
4. Back in Frontdoor, finished up, creating a frontend host for the apex domain then worked.

[image]

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you wont be able to add an SSL for the apex domain at Front Door.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but I struggled a lot with this.

I had this issue with a static web app. I needed this website to be PCI compliant so Azure Front Door was a requirement, but I couldn't make front-door accept the apex domain, and anyone typing the bare domain was getting a "this is not a secure site" (or whatever) message, so what I did is to add the apex domain (example.com) as custom domain at the static web app (this way Azure provided the SSL), and [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) at Azure Frond Door. Btw this last one always worked fine. A redirect at the apex domain does not work if the user types https://example.com instead of http://example.com, so you do need an SSL even for the redirection. At least this was my case.

Anyway, so I handled the redirection by code at the index.html file (Angular) with vanilla javascript at the header

```
  <script>
    let loc = window.location.href;
    loc = loc.replace(/^https?:\/\//, '');
    loc = loc.replace(/\/.*$/, '');
    if (loc != 'www.example.com') {
      window.location.href = 'https://www.example.com';
    }
  </script>
```

It may not be the best solution, but I guess the problem was solved cause we got PCI compliant.